# TypeError: 'click' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLElement for ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am getting the above error for below function : 
The variable SubjectId is global to the window. 
Kindly help.
the application fails when submitted a request through keyboard input.

```
function buyLetterRunner(){
    //  $("#buyLetter").click(function(){
    var restime = (new Date()).getTime() - currenttime;

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"ResponseWriter",
        data:{"SubjectId":SubjectId,
            "response":'buyletter',
            "responsetime":restime
            }
    });
    ......
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to show more code. Sounds like the error is somewhere else.

Comment: http://108.174.62.242:8080/wordGuess/

you can find the complete code on the above link @epascarello.

The filename is wordguess.js

Comment: SubjectID may be undefined, which Ajax may not like.